# How does 'min' 'max' works in Highcharts? I can't get the scrollbar to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

So I have a huge array of data and I'm using `Highcharts's Heatmap`. However I can't get the scrollbar to work, it let me scroll the whole page instead of letting me scroll inside the container. Picture :

[image]

I looked around and found out that it had something to do with `min` and `max` properties. But I have no idea how it's suppose to works, I tried messing with it after read the documentation but no luck so far.

Here's my JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ngendk2o/9/

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command [suppose](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#scrollbar) to be:

```
scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
}
```

Additional you have to set the [xAxis.max](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.max) visible columns on the x axis.

```
xAxis: {
    max: 7  // herewith you define the width 
}
```

Also your [chart.width](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.width) blocks the scrolling as it is defined over the total length, don't use it!

```
    // width: data.length * 3,
```

See the modified jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x26c2f6o/).

Comment: it won't work because adding `width : 800` will make the x axis very very small. Here's the JSFiddle after I change the width to 800. http://jsfiddle.net/ngendk2o/16/

Comment: Yes sorry, `width` doesn't correct your problem. I'm tying to figure out what is the problem..